# How is the serial communication over USB/Bluetooth simulated on a computer?

Tags: bluetooth, python, windows

I am sending a stream of data from an AVR328P (micro mounted on Arduino) to my computer which is running Windows 10. The communication is serial but actually is over bluetooth and a serial port in the computer has been created at the moment I paired the devices. I am receiving the data through the pySerial library in python.

I was wondering how the serial port is emulated by Windows. Is there an hardware UART? If the answer depends on the type of computer I am using, how can I find the description of how it is working? I would also love to know the size in bytes of the input buffer, since I am having problems in receiving the data.

Comment: There isn't a hardware UART, it's all software. How big the buffer is depends on the exact implementation but I would be surprised if it was less that 64 bytes.

Comment: Usually you can check the properties of the emulated COMx port in the Windows Device Manager and the buffer size sometimes is configurable.

Comment: You're asking about how to use windows drivers and first you try a programming website, and now an electronics website. Why don't you first find where your question is on-topic?

Comment: Have a look at the "ioctl()" related functions (e.g. in the Linux framework).  These will give a bit of insight into how hardware protocols are generated/emulated from a software context.  See also "bitbanging" as a general concept.

Comment: Actually, this would belong on stack overflow not here, as it is a *software* question.  But more problematically, it is a badly stated one - you can't even seem to make up your mind if you are asking about bluetooth or USB since your title says one and the body the other.

Comment: Please Chris Stratton see how my answer has been edited.. See what  I wrote: This question was on stack overflow, but it got a lot o bad votes and I deleted to post here

Comment: Questions that are on-topic for a site often get downvotes if they are badly stated, especially if done so in a way that makes the more ignorant fail to understand that they are on-topic.  As a question about the internal working of software virtual devices in a full featured desktop operating sytem, this belongs on Stack Overflow, **not here.**

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering how the serial port is emulated by Windows. Is there an hardware UART?

No. The Bluetooth COM port is software only. The bluetooth module inside a PC is usually connected via USB or PCIe.

> I would also love to know the size in bytes of the input buffer

The "input" buffer is inside the bluetooth module on the microcontroller end. Since there will be latencies due to communication errors, you must use some sort of flow control for decent rates >=115200 baud.

The acutual fifo size varies wildly between modules. I have seen modules with up to about 600 byte buffer and some with *one* byte uart fifo. This *should* be documented in the module's manual.

Comment: So the stream of data is received by the bluetooth, then it goes into USB/PCIe and from there is software emulated as a serial port, is that right?

Comment: This is not correct.  There will be buffers *on both ends* - there have to be, as bluetooth is a *packetized* scheme.   In contrast, operating system serial device APIs are not - you can read and write to serial devices in almost arbitrary size chunks, and the operating system driver will move that data into the hardware UART or in this case bluetooth buffer in whatever manner it accepts or produces it.